# Angular How to pass data from Directive to Parent component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

My requirement is something like, I have a reusable table which I wanna use on multiple places. I am passing table data and columns wherever I am using this table.

Now in some parent components I wanna get data when user click on table row or double click on table row.

For that I have create a directive using @HostListener.

When I am using directive on table row I can get clicked row data in directive but when I am emitting this data I am not getting it in parent.

table.component.html

```
<section class="example-section">

  <div class="cdx-table-wrapper cdx-table-wrapper-fixed">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="tableData" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
            The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

      <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of tableColumns; let colIndex = index" matColumnDef="{{disCol}}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{disCol}}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element[disCol]}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr class="persues-table-row" mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumns"></tr>
      <tr class="persues-table-row" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumns;" appTableEvent [rowData]="row"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

table-events.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTableEvent]'
})
export class TableEventDirective {
  @Input() rowData;

  @Output()
  clickHandler: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClickHandler(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.clickHandler.emit(this);
  }
}
```

parent component

```
<app-table
  [tableData]="dataSourceBase"
  [tableColumns]="displayedColumnsBase"
  (clickHandler)="onRowClick($event)">
</app-table>
```

parent component ts

```
onRowClick(event) {
  console.log('onRowClick', event)
}
```

I am not getting data in `onRowClick()` method.

Now there are some cases when I just wanna use table to just show data, In that case I don't wanna apply directive.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `HostListener` on your table component as well:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table'
})
export class TableComponent {
  @Output()
  clickHandler: EventEmitter<MouseEvent> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

and have this emit from your `appTableEvent` directive:

```
<tr class="persues-table-row" mat-row
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumns;" [rowData]="row"
    appTableEvent (clickHandler)="clickHandler.emit($event)">
</tr>
```

---

If you plan on having multiple of these cases, you can also go for the following solution. You would still need the `clickHandler` on your `TableComponent` like I showed before, but you can update your directive like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTableEvent]'
})
export class TableEventDirective {
  @Input() rowData;

  constructor(@Host() private table: TableComponent) { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClickHandler(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.table.clickHandler.emit(this);
  }
}
```

This way you don't have to add the click handler to the `<tr>` element

Comment: What if I don't have access to table, let's say it's a third-party component. However, I still want to add some functionality to its rows via directive?

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo** in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyok64?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html)

**Here**, you can use `service` and `rxjs - Behaviorsubject`. For this you have to create one service and then in this service define your `Behaviorsubject` and all common communicate related stuff. You have to inject this one service in component and in directive to. so that, dont have to `@Output()` multiple level and one benifit of this you can communicate with any parent level of component regardless of chaining of events.

**table.component.html**

```
<table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th scope="col">ID</th>
       <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
       <th scope="col">Brand</th>
       <th scope="col">Engine Type</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of tableService.tableData; let i = index" appTableRow [rowData]="row">
        <th scope="row">{{row.id}}</th>
        <td>{{row.companyName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.brand}}</td>
        <td>{{row.engineType}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<div *ngIf="selectedRow | async as rowSelect" class="alert alert-primary">
  <pre>
    {{rowSelect | json}}
  </pre>
</div>
```

**table.component.ts**

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedRow;
  constructor(private tableService: TableDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedRow = this.tableService.getTableRow();
  }
}
```

**directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTableRow]'
}) 
export class TableRowDirective {
   @Input() rowData;

   constructor(private tableRowSerivce: TableDataService) { }

   @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
      onClickHandler(event: MouseEvent) {
         this.tableRowSerivce.tableRowData.next(this.rowData);
      }
}
```

**table-service.ts**

```
@Injectable()  
export class TableDataService {

  tableData = [{
   id: 1,
   companyName: 'Audi',
   brand: 'A4',
   engineType: 'Diesel'
  },{
   id: 2,
   companyName: 'Rolls-Roys',
   brand: 'R4',
   engineType: 'Diesel'
  },{
   id: 3,
   companyName: 'Hyundai',
   brand: 'Kona',
   engineType: 'Electric'
  },{
   id: 4,
   companyName: 'Ford',
   brand: 'Endevour',
   engineType: 'Diesel'
 }];

  tableRowData : BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  tableRowData$ = this.tableRowData.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  getTableRow(): Observable<any>{
    return this.tableRowData$;
  }
}
```